# Play Framework requirejs data-main

Tags: javascript

I am new to web development so i was trying to write some sample code to understand how requireJS works. I am using Play-Framework(typesafe-activator-1.3.10).

My sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test page</title>
         <script data-main="assets/javascripts/main.js" src="assets/javascripts/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

My routes file:

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count
GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file:Asset)
```

In my chrome i can see requireJS getting loaded. But its not loading main.js

1. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?
2. My    data-main="assets/javascripts/main.js" but URL is    "hxxx://localhost:9000/main.js" Should it not be    hxxx://localhost:9000/javascripts/main.js

[image]

Comment: you need to remove the '.js' from 'main.js'

Answer (score 0):

You should change your:

```
<script data-main="assets/javascripts/main.js" ....></script>
```

in

```
<script data-main="assets/javascripts/main" ...."></script>
```

When you load files with requirejs, you don't need to specify the `.js` extension

Comment: I updated and removed .js extension. Its still not working. Link to my test project https://github.com/adityanp/PlayTest.git